# Adding elements to a list in a for loop

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
var locations: List[Location] = List[Location]()
for (x <- 0 to 10; y <- 0 to 10) {
    println("x: " + x + " y: " + y)
    locations ::: List(Location(x, y))
    println(locations)
}
```

The code  above is supposed to concatenate some lists. But the result is an empty list. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is on the line `locations ::: List(Location(x, y))`. This is concatenating the lists, but the doing nothing with the result. If you replace it with `locations = locations ::: List(Location(x, y))` you would have your desired result.

However there are more idiomatic ways to solve this problem in Scala. In Scala, writing immutable code is the preferred style (i.e. use `val` rather than `var` where possible).

Here's a couple of ways to do it:

Using yield:

```
val location = for (x <- 0 to 10; y <- 0 to 10) yield Location(x, y)
```

Using tabulate:

```
val location = List.tabulate(11, 11) { case (x, y) => Location(x, y) }
```

Even shorter:

```
val location = List.tabulate(11, 11)(Location)
```

Edit: just noticed you had `0 to 10` which is inclusive-inclusive. `0 until 10` is inclusive-exclusive. I've changed the args to tabulate to 11.